# KStreams : How do you get the (originating) topic of a record?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have the following

```java
//Config setup
Properties props = ...; //setup

List<String> topicList = Arrays.asList({"A", "B", "C"});

StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder();
KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(topicList);

source
  .map((k,v) -> {

    //How can i get the topic of the record here

  })
  .to((k,v,r) -> {//busy code for topic routing});

new KafkaStream(builder.build(), properties).start();
```

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#accessing-record-metadata-such-as-topic-partition-and-offset-information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a topic name you need using [ProcessorContext.topic()](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorContext.html#topic--).
To get an access to ProcessorContext use KStream.process() providing it with an appropriate [Processor](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/Processor.html) implementation.

Also you can use KStream.transform():

```
KStream<InputKeyType, InputValueType> stream2 = stream.transform(new TransformerSupplier<InputKeyType, InputValueType, KeyValue<OutputKeyType, OutputValueType>>() {
            @Override
            public Transformer<InputKeyType, InputValueType, KeyValue<OutputKeyType, OutputValueType>> get() {
                return new Transformer<InputKeyType, InputValueType, KeyValue<OutputKeyType, OutputValueType>>() {
                    private ProcessorContext context;

                    @Override
                    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
                        this.context = context;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public KeyValue<OutputKeyType, OutputValueType> transform(InputKeyType key, InputValueType value) {

                        this.context.topic() // topic name you need
                        // logic here
                        return new KeyValue<>(OutputKeyType key, OutputValueType value);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void close() {

                    }
                };
            }
        });
```